App doesn't go "true" fullscreen occasionally
I'm using a Macbook Pro with M2 chip and Sonoma 14.4.1.
Sometimes I found my app doesn't go fullscreen such that even after clicking the green full-screen button or holding and selecting "full-screen mode", it is still windowed and only occupies a (large though) portion of the screen except for the menu bar and dock area. See the screenshot below:

It seems this happens randomly. Does anyone know (1) why this happens and (2) how to fix it?

Does it only happen in specific applications like Steam (where I see the same behaviour)?

@nohillside It didn't occur often (or sometimes I didn't notice), but I honestly don't recall if this happened to Steam more than once before. It also happened to GeForceNow though.

On a Mac with a "notch", full screen (when correctly implemented) provides the app with a complete rectangle below the notch and covering the Dock.
The space each side of the notch is "extra" screen space. Note that the menu bar remains hidden most of the time when in full screen.
True full screen will cover the Dock area too - try full screen in Safari or Finder.
Your app, Steam, is not using Full Screen mode to its full potential as the Dock is still visible. Steam has changed to a lesser full screen (maximise window) which leaves the Dock. Maybe you should contact Stream about this.
When you "hover" over the green traffic light, a correctly implemented app with show a drop down with three choice (full screen, left half or right half). Steam does not do this.

Thank you Gilby. So I suppose this is per-app issue instead of global issue on Mac in general?

@GrumpyCivet Yes, I am sure it is a per-app issue.  I assume that each app is able to determine the exact role of the green button.
